# как отправить json запрос в slim'е

Tags: php, rest, slim

Есть рабочий запрос к api:

```
curl -X "POST" "http://localhost:8081/oauth/auth" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "Accept: application/json" \
    --data '{"grant_type":"password", "client_id":"app", "client_secret":"", "username":"oauth@example.com", "password":"password"}'
```

Пытаюсь отправить его в тестах. Делаю вот так:

```
use Zend\Diactoros\Stream;
use Zend\Diactoros\Response;
use Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequest;
use Slim\App;

$body = new Stream('php://temp', 'r+');
$body->write(json_encode($params));
$body->rewind();

$request = (new ServerRequest())
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        ->withHeader('Accept', 'application/json')
        ->withUri(new Uri($uri))
        ->withMethod($method)
        ->withBody($body);

$container = $this->container();
$app = new App($container);
(require 'config/routes.php')($app, $container);

$responce = $app->process($request, new Response());
$responce->getBody()->rewind();
```

в ответ приходит эксепшен, что не распарсился параметр grant_type

Answer (score 0):

Метод `withBody()` не влияет на результат метода `getParsedBody()`, а коде обработчика скорее всего используется именно метод `$request->getParsedBody()`.

Попробуйте при инициализации объекта запроса установить значение распарсенного тела.

```php
<?php

$request = (new ServerRequest())
        ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        ->withHeader('Accept', 'application/json')
        ->withUri(new Uri($uri))
        ->withMethod($method)
        ->withBody($body)
        ->withParsedBody($params);
```